# Comma before a participle

Tags: punctuation

My question might be a duplicate, but I've tried to find an answer, searching this site, - haven't succeeded, though.

Is it correct to put a comma in the following sentence?

1. I spent the next three years recovering from a severe injury.
2. I spent the next three years, recovering from a severe injury.

Whether the comma is needed or not, please, explain to me why as I thought we put a comma if either participle or a participle phrase is separated from the word it is modifying. And in the example, the phrase is actually separated from "I spent".

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It is not correct to put a comma there.  I also don't think it is correct to say "we put a comma if either participle or a participle phrase is separated from the word it is modifying" as a general rule: e.g., "he ran home crying", not "he ran home, crying."  But I will let someone with more technical knowledge of grammar explain the exact rules.

Comment: Commas don't really "mean" anything - they're only there to reflect ***pauses in speech***. And since no-one would pause after the word ***years*** in your example, there's no reason to include a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I spent the next three years recovering from a severe injury.

> 2. I spent the next three years, recovering from a severe injury.

Generally, commas are of the four types: the listing comma, the joining comma, the gapping comma, and the bracketing commas.

In example 2, by the process of elimination, we deduce that the comma has to be a bracketing comma, used to bracket a weak interruption.

It is clear that with the *weak interruption* removed, the remaining part of the clause does not convey the intended message.

> I spent the next three years.

We should hence not have that comma.

Comment: If the verb in the initial clause had been, say, ***wasted*** rather than ***spent***, it would be entirely optional whether to include a comma / pause in  *I spent the next three years [comma / pause] recovering from a severe injury*.

Comment: But I'll still have to use comma in the sentence: "I found him, crying his name"? I mean, if I want to say that I was crying his name in order to find him.